# How to customize JSONBuilder results in Groovy?

Tags: groovy

The below Groovy code produces the result shown under *Current Result*. How do I customize the JSON output as shown in *Expected Output*?

```
def resultset = Sql.newInstance(...).rows('select * from client')
println new JsonBuilder(clients:resultset).toPrettyString()
```

**Current Result**

```
{
    "clients": [
        {
            "ID": 1,
            "NAME": "ABC",
            "ADDR1": "123 MAIN ST",
            "ADDR2": "NEW YORK",
            "ZIP": "12345"
        },
        {
            "ID": 2,
            "NAME": "XYZ",
            "ADDR1": "321 MAIN ST",
            "ADDR2": "NEW JERSEY",
            "ZIP": "98761"
        }
    ]
}
```

Do I need to loop through each row and customize?

**Expected**

```
{
    "clients": [
        {
            "ID": 1,
            "NAME": "ABC",
            "CONTACT": {
                "ADDR1": "123 MAIN ST",
                "ADDR2": "NEW YORK",
                "ZIP": "12345"
            }
        },
        {
            "ID": 2,
            "NAME": "XYZ",
            "CONTACT": {
                "ADDR1": "321 MAIN ST",
                "ADDR2": "NEW JERSEY",
                "ZIP": "98761"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below should work (but I'm not sure cause there's no full example provided):

```
println new JsonBuilder(clients:resultset.collect {[
   ID: it.ID,
   NAME: it.NAME,
   CONTACT: [
      ADDR1: it.ADDR1,
      ADDR2: it.ADDR2,
      ZIP: it.ZIP,
   ],
]}).toPrettyString()
```

Try it and let me know in case of any problems. Do You understand how it works?

Comment: It worked very well. Thank you. I am fairly new to Groovy and I understand that Metaprogramming constructs are work here where a dynamic method is added for keys like ID, NAME. etc. I'm not sure if I got that right, but I haven't explore that area deeply yet. I'd appreciate if you could briefly explain how it works.

Comment: You're welcome. It has nothing to do with metaprogramming. Here `collect` statement is used which applies given closure to every element of a collection and returns the modified collections. You need to read about groovy basics - collections, closures. It's really easy.

Comment: Thanks. I am familiar with closures and groovy iterator patterns. I thought you were asking about how JSONBuilder works. I guess JSONBuilder takes any object as input, and converts each field or key-value into JSON elements. This is something I haven't verified and yet to dig deeper.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry for misunderstanding. Yes, this is more or less how it works.